# C program not giving desired output

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int f,x,s,y,t,l,year,sum;

  f=year/1000;
  x=year%1000;
  s=x/100;
  y=x%100;
  t=y/10;
  l=y%10;
  sum=f+s+t+l;

    printf("Enter a Year:");
    scanf("%d",&year);

    if (year%4==0){
        printf("Leap,%d",sum);
    }
    else if (year%400==0){
    printf("Leap,%d",sum);
    }
    else if (year%100==0){
        printf("Regular,%d",sum);
    }
    else {printf("Regular,%d",sum);}
    return 0;
}
```

Obejective: Input a 4 digit year using stdin (scanf). Display whether it is a leap year or not. If it is a leap year, display - Leap,sum of digits of year. If not a leap year, display - Regular,sum of digits of year.

Its giving correct output for leap year but not the sum of the digits

Comment: Well, you're calculating the sum BEFORE you read the year from the user. You have to do it after.

Comment: The PC starts at the beginning of `main()` and evaluates one statement after the other. (Simply speaking, startup routine, signals, interrupts, multithreading, stack unwinding .... ignored). Ignoring the return value of `scanf()` is a programming error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expressions in C are not formulas that automatically take effect when the associated variables change.  They work on the *current* value of the variables in question *at that point in the program*.

You need to move the digit calculation to *after* you read the value of `year`.

```
printf("Enter a Year:");
scanf("%d",&year);

f=year/1000;
x=year%1000;
s=x/100;
y=x%100;
t=y/10;
l=y%10;
sum=f+s+t+l;
```

Also, you'll want to take another look at how you do the leap year calculation.  Try 1900, 1999, 2000, and 2004 as test values.

Comment: Not checking the return value of `scanf()` is a error.

Answer (score 1):

Your actual question was answered by @dbush, however, your leap year criteria are also not quite right. Your first `if` branch will always execute when `year % 4 == 0` regardless of whether `year % 100 == 0`. So what you really want there is

```
if(year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0)) {
 // leap year ...
}
else {
 // no leap year ...
}
```